# compare one value against an array

Tags: php, mysql, ternary-operator

I am trying to compare a value pulled from mysql against an array pulled from mysql. The code looks like this:

```
$aeSelect = "SELECT id, firstName, lastName from user WHERE fiID = 0 AND access = 3 ORDER BY lastName";
$aeQuery = mysql_query($aeSelect) or die ("Could not get AE list: " . mysql_error());
while ($rowAE = mysql_fetch_array($aeQuery)) {
   echo "<option " . (($row['aeid'] == $rowAE['id']) ? "selected='selected'" : "") . ">" . $rowAE['firstName'] . " " . $rowAE['lastName'] . "</option>";
}
```

`$row['aeid']` is 20022 and `$rowAE['id']` is a list of ids of the AEs.

I cannot be doing this right because the select menu is displaying all the names of the AEs but not making the correct one selected. Why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how variable $row is initialized?

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm just going to say that in this day and age it is a little silly not to use a framework such as Yii or Cake for DB access in PHP unless this is a very small site.

Having said that, the problem you are having is a simple fix:

```
$aeSelect = "SELECT id, firstName, lastName from user WHERE fiID = 0 AND access = 3 ORDER BY lastName";
$aeQuery = mysql_query($aeSelect) or die ("Could not get AE list: " . mysql_error());
while ($rowAE = mysql_fetch_array($aeQuery)) {
   echo "<option " . (($row['aeid'] == $rowAE['id']) ? "selected='selected'" : "") . ' value="'. $rowAE['id']. "\">" . $rowAE['firstName'] . " " . $rowAE['lastName'] . "</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change option row into this:

```
echo "<option ";
if ($row['aeid'] == $rowAE['id']) echo 'selected="selected"';
echo  ' value="'.$rowAE['id'].'">' . $rowAE['firstName'] . ' '. $rowAE['lastName'] . '</option>';
```

I hope it is good :)